# Do I need to worry about series rearrangement in this case?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So let's say I have a series that looks like this:

$S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^n\cdot\frac{x+n}{n^2}}$

I can prove it converges by the alternating series test and I was trying to prove that it's affine in $x$ like this:

If we define $L(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^n\cdot\frac{x}{n^2}}$ and $C(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^n\cdot\frac{n}{n^2}}$ then we can see that $S(x)=L(x)+C(x)$. Then, we can see that:

- $L(0)=0$, $L(cx)=cL(x)$, and $L(x+y)=L(x)+L(y)$ so $L$ is linear.
- $C(x)$ is constant (independent of $x$).

Therefore, $S(x)$ is affine.

Now, here is my concern. Although $S(x)$ converges, it doesn't converge absolutely, so it converges conditionally. Thus, it can be rearranged so that the series converges to anything we want. Does that create a problem for my proof because it is (kind of) a rearrangement?

Comment: For the convergence of alternating series, it is sufficient that the sequence of the absolute values strictly decreases and tends to $0$. This is the case here if the starting index is sufficiently large.

Comment: @Peter yeah, that is the alternating series test I mentioned. My concern is not with proving that that series converges, it is with my attempt to prove that the series converges to an affine function in $x$.

Comment: There seems to be no rearrangement in your proof.

Comment: @CrackedBauxite is it not a rearrangement to split it up into two different series? In my proof, $L(x)$ has the terms like $x/n^2$ and $C(x)$ has the terms like $n/n^2$ (both alternating). This may not technically be a rearrangement, but does it create the same problems?

Comment: all you've done is use the fact that for two convergent series (namely $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$; the first actually converges absolutely, so no issues at all there, and the second converges. Sure, conditionally, but still converges), we can add them and scalar multiply them (by $x$), and all the basic rules still hold here. This proves your original series is an affine function of $x$. There is no rearrangmement/cause for concern here.

Comment: @peek-a-boo so "splitting" it doesn't cause a rearrangement problem? Let's say that you have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n(a_n+b_n)$ which converges conditionally but not absolutely and the same is true of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n(a_n)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n(b_n)$. Is it always the case that: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n(a_n+b_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n(a_n) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n(b_n)$?

Comment: yes. Call $\alpha_n=(-1)^na_n$ and $\beta_n=(-1)^nb_n$. What you're asking is just the following simple theorem: "If $\{\alpha_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $\{\beta_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are summable sequences (in more traditional terminology, the series $\sum\alpha_n,\sum\beta_n$ converge), then $\{\alpha_n+\beta_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is summable, and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\alpha_n+\beta_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\alpha_n+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\beta_n$ ". This follows immediately by considering partial sums, and using the basic limit laws for addition.

Comment: Rearrangement is when you're actually rearranging stuff. i.e take a bijection $\sigma:\Bbb{N}\to\Bbb{N}$. Then, in general, $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ being a summable sequence (i.e $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^na_i$ existing in $\Bbb{R}$) doesn't imply that $\{a_{\sigma(n)}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is summable. Or even if it is summable, there's no guarantee the sums are the same (if we rearrange only finitely many terms, there's no issues, because of commutativity of addition for two, hence finitely many numbers. The issue is in the general case). But this is not at all what is going on here.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks! I guess I was using "rearrangement" by metaphor because I was thinking "if rearrangement can cause problems, can't splitting?" But your argument clears that up!